# The request was aborted: Failed to create SSL / TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, ssl

There is a Windows service written in C #. Perhaps after restarting it began to give an error: "The request was interrupted: could not create a secure SSL / TLS channel" when accessing another service that is located on another server via https.

The example code in the service is like this

```
private void Somewhere() {
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AlwaysGoodCertificate);}
private static bool AlwaysGoodCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors) {return true;}
```

Tried to add in the program code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Did not help. I also tried this code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Also did not help, how to fix this problem?

Comment: I've encountered a similar issue. I was attempting to use a webservice hosted on a Linux machine from a Windows 2008 server. Using a program called IISCrypto on the Windows server and running syllabs against the Linux server I found out there were no compatible protocols/ciphers between the client and server. Updating to Windows 2016 did the trick.

Comment: What version of the framework is used by your service?

Comment: @Steve, .Net 4.8

Comment: Not sure if it could be of any help in your context. This links explains how to force the use of TLS12 https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb510.aspx I have resolved a problem on my side, but the context is different. The errore message was the same but my application was very old.